# SQL Server - An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: sql-server

We are getting the error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'" while trying the below condition. What could be the problem, please advise.

```
where reports.folio_instruments.report_date = (
    Select Max(folio_instruments.report_date) 
    from reports.folio_instruments
)
```

Regards,
Sri.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in this part of the query.

Comment: Please post the complete query

Comment: use **aliases** for tables

Comment: Hi, I am using this SQL query in IDT Tool of SAP BO. We have identified the problem in BO, not in SQL. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You might want to either re-tag this question, then, or delete it and create another.